# Twitter Bootstrap - Inline Form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have this form:

```
<!-- First Name-->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="textinput" name="Product Name" class="input-xlarge" type="text"> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Last Name-->
    <div class="control-group inline">
      <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="textinput" name="Product Name" class="input-xlarge" type="text"> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Telefonnumber-->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Telefonnumber</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="textinput" name="Product Name" class="input-xlarge" type="text"> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Street-->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Street</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="textinput" name="Product Name" class="input-xlarge" type="text"> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to display Last Name next to First Name and under these two field the Telefonnumber.

How can I realize this in twitter bootstrap?

btw the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3101/)

Comment: wtf? whats wrong with my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I think your jsfiddle link is pointing to the wrong version of your example...

Comment: They likely thought you should read the reference material first and/or didn't like that your jsfiddle didn't work.  I updated your fiddle and here is the documentation that goes over how to do page layout with bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: thx for your answer! However, I thought that there is possibly a css class `.form-inline` or sth. to fix this problem quickly without using `span6` ect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstraps has a few example form layouts that you can [use here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).

As per their documentation, use `controls-row` when you want multiple on a line.  (`form-inline` is for the whole form to be inline).  You will want to read their [scaffolding documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) before going forward with using their classes.

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3102/)

**PS.. HTML pointers**

1. Don't duplicate `id` (and `name` if you can avoid it).  For example, `id="textinput"` should be unique across the entire page.  The `name` doesn't have to be unique, but it's best practice to just match the id.
2. Add `for` attribute to labels.